# Hidden overflow interrupts animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a bit of a complex question here but I will try my best.
So I have created an animation, on my page there is a `<div>` with `overflow: hidden`, the animation stops on this location for a few seconds and then continues, any idea, how i could fix this?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".scrollTo").on('click', function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     var target = $(this).attr('href');
     $('html, body').animate({
       scrollTop: ($(target).offset().top)
     }, 2000);
  });
});
```

```css
#two {
  height: 110vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="test">
  <li><a href="#three" class="scrollTo" data-content="">tutorials</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Fixed by chaning height: 110vh; to min-height: 110vh; and removing the overflow

Answer (score 0):

The `overflow:` property set to `hidden` has caused a glitch in your animation at the said location.

A little definition of the `overflow` property

**The overflow property specifies what happens if content overflows an element's box.
This property specifies whether to clip content or to add scrollbars when an element's content is too big to fit in a specified area.**

Try setting the `overflow` property to `auto`, `scroll` or `visible` and check to see if this fix the glitch